# Removing graphics from bottom of elegantbook page

Tags: templates

I am using the "elegantbook" document class,

```
\documentclass[fancy,11pt,twocol]{elegantbook}
```

But the template has a graphic at the bottom of the page that I'd like to remove:
[image]

What can I delete in the template to remove these?

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the code (or the link to the code) of the style of the document you are using? It is likely to be imported in the preamble using `\usepackage`

Comment: @bgleb Nah. It is in the class, which is a standard one, as given in the question. However, a minimal working example would make it easier to give a good answer and reduce the need for guesswork.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@cfr's answer does the job i.e. removing the footer. The [`elegantbook` package documentation](https://ctan.org/pkg/elegantbook) also mentions

> Hiding the end-of-chapter and end-of-page base is optional, simply type in:
>
> ```
> \documentclass[hide]{elegantbook} %or
> \documentclass[base=hide]{elegantbook}
> ```

This would replace the ornament with page numbers instead.

Answer (score 2):

Without example code to play with, it is not possible to say for sure. However, to hazard a guess:

Add the following to your document's preamble:

```
\renewcommand{\base}[2]{}
```

Or you might want

```
\renewcommand\base[2]{\par}
```